# Is there a way to get the currently executing file from sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server

If I call sqlcmd with the -i command line switch, I'd like to be able to get the name of the file.  So, I call

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -E -i filename.sql
```

I'd like to be able to somehow have the contents of the script be able to print the filename without having to hard code it in the file.  Looking at the variables and commands that are documented in BOL, I don't see anything like this, but just wanted to make sure.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Among the list of [sqlcmd Scripting Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx), I don't see anything that has the name for the input file.

But you can send the file name as a parameter when you call sqlcmd.

**Input file (filename.sql)**

```
PRINT '$(p1)'
```

**Sqlcmd:**

```
sqlcmd -S .\Server -i filename.sql -v p1="filename.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should explore powershell for this